# ASP.NET Web Forms: Use same tagPrefix for web controls from different namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I've [registered two namespaces](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config) in `Web.config` like this:

```
<add tagPrefix="a" assembly="WebApplication1" namespace="WebFormsApplication1.Controls1" />
<add tagPrefix="a" assembly="WebApplication1" namespace="WebFormsApplication1.Controls2" />
```

I'm using them like this in an `.aspx` page:

```
<a:WebCustomControl1 ID="Control1" runat="server"></a:WebCustomControl1>
<a:WebCustomControl2 ID="Control2" runat="server"></a:WebCustomControl2>
```

Here's the (broken) `.designer.cs` file VS generates for that page (notice that it uses `Controls2` namespace for both controls, although `Control1` lays in `Controls1` namespace):

```
protected global::WebFormsApplication1.Controls2.WebCustomControl1 Control1;
protected global::WebFormsApplication1.Controls2.WebCustomControl2 Control2;
```

It looks like the second `<add` in Web.config is overwriting the first one.
I want it to append rather than overwrite, is it possible?

---

I guess there are other alternatives as well:

1. Put everything in a single namespace
2. Use an unique `tagPrefix` for each namespace

But they are not cool since we have about a hujilion of controls here.

Notice that if register the namespaces in `aspx` itself, it'll work fine:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="a" Namespace="WebFormsApplication1.Controls2" Assembly="WebFormsApplication1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="a" Namespace="WebFormsApplication1.Controls" Assembly="WebFormsApplication1" %>
```

So it looks like some bug in `Web.config` parsing.

(I'm on VS 2017, but they told me it happened since VS 2010 at least).

Comment: Don't.  It can cause unpredictable results due to namespace shadowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases where I needed this in the past, I had deleted the designer files and Manually declared all the controls in the code behind.

There may also be a way (but I don't recall exactly how) to tell the Designer to not generate those specific controls in the designer file. Then you manually add them in the code behind.